# How to determine the named range from position in Google Docs through Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am looking at a way to determine the named range in Google docs through Google Apps Script for the current cursor position. Is there anyway to do that?

Context:
I am marking a range in the google document for review using named range. I would like to get the named range if the cursor is placed in that location of the document so that I can show that there is a review item on that area.

Could you please let me know if there is a way to do that in Google Apps Script?
thanks
Jasper

Comment: What if there are 15 named ranges that contain the cell where the cursor is placed?

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342164/getrange-with-named-range-google-spreadsheet-using-scripts

Comment: @sandwich, I would like to get all the named ranges for the current position.

Comment: @d.datul1990 the reference is not helping as it is for Google Sheets in a different context. I am looking for Google Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
```

cursor is a "Position".

A "Position" can tell you several things, for example the element which holds the position.
Be careful: The thinking of a position is quite opposite:
A position cannot contain other elements.
A position is contained *within* an element.

So i think you could search your named ranges for this element:

```
cursor.getElement()
```

You have to iterate through your ranges, i think and if there is a match ... bingo.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Richard. This is the kind of approach that I have been trying. But this is a brute force approach (still not reached solution though). I am wondering if there is any elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, i know what you mean. It's terrible, i know. i searched for a solution of a problem i had with bookmarks.
This is very similar with the cursor and ranges.

Comment: But more as the Element the Position resides in or the surrounding text of the Position is not availlale.

Comment: So you have to use either the Element itself or the surrounding text to search for the Position within your document or named ranges.

It's a brute force method, yes, but nothing else is availlable.
I'm sorry, too.

But i can help you find your ranges if you provide me a testdocument with some overlapping named ranges, if you like.

It's really not that hard to locate all the named ranges your cursor is in.